# Returning to or starting a Java activity, natively

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-ndk

My application launches its main activity in Java, which in turn launches my purely native activity (i.e. it enters android_main as provided by android_native_app_glue.h).

I would now like to be able to either:
- finish the native activity and have it return to my main Java activity, or 
- start a new Java Activity.

How can I do either of these, natively in C++?

I also need to be able to pass some data from my native activity to my Java activity. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are my posts on google groups regarding this question. I ended up having to use exit(), to exit a native activity.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_frm/thread/a630d0f1de886e81/91025438f5dd91c8?lnk=gst&q=lost_bits1110#91025438f5dd91c8
http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_frm/thread/45286134315869cd/d60d7f8d02054dd6?lnk=gst&q=lost_bits1110#d60d7f8d02054dd6